# Why doesn't ag-grid always update after removing a row from the rowData ref value?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I am finding that in ag-grid community edition using vue, if I remove one row from the rowData array, the row removed is immediately removed from the grid. I can see the update right away. But any subsequent rows removed from rowData have no effect and are not removed from the grid.

Is there a way to force the grid to pick up these removed rows? I tried refreshCells and redrawRows without luck.

I have a demo of this behavior here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/r1o2N6DzOF1t8BPB?open=main.js

```
import { ModuleRegistry } from '@ag-grid-community/core';
import '@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import '@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import { AgGridVue } from '@ag-grid-community/vue3';
import { createApp, onBeforeMount, ref } from 'vue';

// Register the required feature modules with the Grid
ModuleRegistry.registerModules([ClientSideRowModelModule]);

const VueExample = {
  template: `
        <div style="height: 100%">
       
            <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
             {{ deleteUpdateInfo }}
                <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; min-height: 30px;">
                    <button v-on:click="deleteRow(2)">Delete row 3 </button>
                </div>
                <div style="flex: 1 1 0px;">
                    <ag-grid-vue
                
                style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
                class="ag-theme-alpine"
                :columnDefs="columnDefs"
                @grid-ready="onGridReady"
                :rowData="rowData"
                :rowSelection="rowSelection"
                :animateRows="true"></ag-grid-vue>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
  components: {
    'ag-grid-vue': AgGridVue,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const columnDefs = ref([
      { field: 'make' },
      { field: 'model' },
      { field: 'price' },
    ]);
    const gridApi = ref();
    const gridColumnApi = ref();

    const rowData = ref(null);
    const rowSelection = ref(null);
    const deleteUpdateInfo = ref('')
    onBeforeMount(() => {
      rowSelection.value = 'single';
    });

    const deleteRow = (rIndex) => {
      deleteUpdateInfo.value = `deleting row ${rIndex +1} containing ${rowData.value[rIndex].make} from data. Current row size is ${rowData.value.length}... `
      rowData.value.splice(rIndex,1)
      deleteUpdateInfo.value = `${deleteUpdateInfo.value} row deleted. Now row size is ${rowData.value.length}`
      console.log(deleteUpdateInfo.value)
    }
    const onRowDataA = () => {
      gridApi.value.setRowData(rowDataA);
    };
    const onRowDataB = () => {
      gridApi.value.setRowData(rowDataB);
    };
    const onGridReady = (params) => {
      gridApi.value = params.api;
      gridColumnApi.value = params.columnApi;
      // specify the data
    rowData.value = [
      { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
      { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxster', price: 72000 },
      { make: 'Aston Martin', model: 'DBX', price: 190000 },

      { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
      { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
      { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxster', price: 72000 },
      { make: 'BMW', model: 'M50', price: 60000 },
      { make: 'Aston Martin', model: 'DBX', price: 190000 },
    ];
    };

    return {
      columnDefs,
      gridApi,
      gridColumnApi,
      rowData,
      rowSelection,
      onGridReady,
      onRowDataA,
      onRowDataB,
      deleteRow,
      deleteUpdateInfo
    };
  },
};



createApp(VueExample).mount('#app');
```

Comment: Doesn't feel as clean as it should be, but if you add 
      gridApi.value.setRowData(rowData.value) after deleting the row it updates the table.

Comment: Tried that in the above code sample and it did fix the problem! However, in my real code which is more complex, with various cell renderers, it's causing side effects. Going to try to get it working there, next.

Comment: Since I passed a ref to rowData to the Grid Options, you would think that the grid would pick up on the change automatically without this call.

Comment: Yea, AG Grid doesn't feel as easy to work with composition api as it did with options api, specially before v27, where it just worked(at least for me), i've gone thru same things you're going before, it always seems like a multiple workarounds instead of working as expected/it did before.

Answer (score 1):

This works in the sample code included in the question:

```
gridApi.value.setRowData(rowData.value)
```

In my codebase this fix was generating an error.

> ag-grid-community.auto.esm.js:36619 Uncaught Error: AG Grid: cannot get grid to draw rows when it is in the middle of drawing rows.

But this worked:

```
setTimeout(function() { gridApi.setRowData(rowData.value); }, 0)
```